# Subject calling next() is not seen by Component subscriptions

Tags: angular, rxjs

every time I try to subscribe to this subject it gives me the following

> core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HomeCompComponent -> PickStoreCompComponent]: 
>     StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HomeCompComponent -> PickStoreCompComponent]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for PickStoreCompComponent!
>   NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HomeCompComponent -> PickStoreCompComponent]: 
>     StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HomeCompComponent -> PickStoreCompComponent]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for PickStoreCompComponent!

I tried to add PickStoreCompComponent to app.module.ts, error goes away but next() is not seen by the subscriptions

pick-store-comp.component.ts

```
import { DataStorgeService } from 'src/app/data-storge.service';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pick-store-comp',
  templateUrl: './pick-store-comp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pick-store-comp.component.scss']
})
export class PickStoreCompComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private data: DataStorgeService) {}

  storesfire = new Subject<any>();
  allCouponsData = [];
  selectedCoupon;
  onStoreClick() {
    this.storesfire.next(this.selectedCoupon);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.allCouponsData = this.data.allCoupons;
  }
}
```

home-comp.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PickStoreCompComponent } from '../pick-store-comp/pick-store-comp.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-comp',
  templateUrl: './home-comp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home-comp.component.scss']
})
export class HomeCompComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private storesData: PickStoreCompComponent) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.storesData.storesfire.subscribe((data) => {
      console.log('test');
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't inject instances of components into other components. You should move your subject into a service and inject the service into both components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't inject components into other components. Components can interact in different ways - that isn't one of them.

In your case I would recommend a shared service. Inject the service into the two components that interact. The service creates a subject. One component sends values into the subject, the other subscribes.

store.service.ts

```js
// declare singleton service so that both components use a shared instance
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StoreService {
  // use ReplaySubject if you want subscribers to receive an 
  // existing value on subscription
  private storesFire = new ReplaySubject<any>(1);

  // prefer exposing the subject via your own API rather than directly

  getSelectedCoupon(): Observable<any> {
    return this.storesFire.asObservable();
  }

  selectCoupon(coupon) {
    this.storesFire.next(coupon);
  }
}
```

pick-store.component.ts

```js
export class PickStoreCompComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private data: DataStorageService,
    private storeService: StoreService
  ) {}

  allCouponsData = [];
  selectedCoupon;

  onStoreClick() {
    this.storeService.selectCoupon(this.selectedCoupon);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.allCouponsData = this.data.allCoupons;
  }
}
```

home.component.ts

```js
export class HomeCompComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private storeService: StoreService) {}

  private destroyed = new Subject();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.storeService.getSelectedCoupon.pipe(
      // unsubscribe on destroy
      takeUntil(this.destroyed)
    ).subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroyed.next();
    this.destroyed.complete();
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much
what about this!
Property 'storesFire' does not exist on type 'storeService'. Did you mean 'storesfire'?